# Jenkins Pipeline SCM failover

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

My Jenkins Pipeline Script code is managed by the Bitbucket repository.
The selection of Jenkins Job Definition is Pipeline script from SCM.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ngza4.png)

When building the Jenkins Job, the code in bitbucket is checked out and executed.

If the bitbucket server is down or is unable to check out of the bitbucket due to an unexpected issue, is there a way to run it with the code checked out of the previous build?
Or is there another way to set up failover?